# Simplify $x^2\sin{\left({\frac{x}{2}}\right)}\cos{\left({\frac{x}{2}}\right)}$

Tags: trigonometry

In this problem I need to simplify the following expression:

$$x^2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\cos{\frac{x}{2}}$$

However, I can't think of any trigonometric properties or algebraic manipulations that would simplify it. I know this isn't a proper way to ask a question here, without showing any working, but any ideas or hints would be appreciated :)

Comment: Use $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: $x^2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}$ is not an *equation*. Do you want to simplify this *expression*?

Comment: @amsmathim guessing thats the fully simplified equation, but im interested in knowing how to simplify it, rather than just knowing the answer

Comment: The given expression, a product of algebra and trig, is as simple as it can get.

Comment: this requires you to know $\sin(a+b)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that

$$\sin 2\theta =2\sin \theta \cos \theta \implies \sin \theta \cos \theta=\frac12\sin 2\theta $$

therefore with $\theta=\frac x 2$ we have

$$x^2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\cos{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac12x^2\sin x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sin x = 2 \sin (x/2) \cos (x/2) $$

Thus we have $$ x^2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\cos{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac12x^2\sin x$$

No more simplification is possible.